# Why should the slot function which receives signals for the standard output be in the main thread when making a GUI by PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a GUI made by PyQT5. It has a painTextEdit widget to which I want to redirect the standard output of my worker thread. I create a class called "Stream" to emit signals which carry the standard out of the worker thread and a slot function called "update_text" will receive the signal from "Stream".

However, I found that if I create the slot function "update_text" inside the class for worker thread (called "Worker"), the painTextEdit widget only shows part of the standard output of the worker thread. On the other hands, after I move the function "update_text" to the class for the main stream, the standard output can be displayed completely.

Below is the sample of my main program in which the slot function "update_text" is implemented inside the class (called "Worker") for the worker thread. And it can only show part of the standard output on the GUI.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from main_window import Ui_Form
import sys

class Stream(QtCore.QObject):

    newText = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def write(self, data: str):
        self.newText.emit(data)

class Worker(QtCore.QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, displayer: QtWidgets.QWidget):
        super().__init__()
        self.displayer = displayer
        sys.stdout = Stream(newText = self.update_text)

    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 101):
            sys.stdout.write(f'{i}\n')

    def update_text(self, consoleOutput: str):
        cursor = self.displayer.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(consoleOutput)
        self.displayer.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.displayer.ensureCursorVisible()

class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.threadPool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
        self.pushButtonStart.clicked.connect(self.start_working)

    def start_working(self):
        displayer = self.plainTextEdit
        worker = Worker(displayer)
        self.threadPool.start(worker.run)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Below is another version of my program in which the slot function "update_text" is implemented inside the class (called "MyMainWindow") for the main thread. And it works fine.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from main_window import Ui_Form
import sys

class Stream(QtCore.QObject):

    newText = QtCore.pyqtSignal(tuple)

    def write(self, data: tuple):
        self.newText.emit(data)

class Worker(QtCore.QRunnable):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self, displayer: QtWidgets.QWidget):
        for i in range(1, 1001):
            data = (f'{i}\n', displayer)
            sys.stdout.write(data)

class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.threadPool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
        sys.stdout = Stream(newText = self.update_text)
        self.pushButtonStart.clicked.connect(self.start_working)

    def start_working(self):
        displayer = self.plainTextEdit
        worker = Worker()
        self.threadPool.start(lambda: worker.run(displayer))

    def update_text(self, data: tuple):
        consoleOutput, displayer = data
        cursor = displayer.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(consoleOutput)
        displayer.setTextCursor(cursor)
        displayer.ensureCursorVisible()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyMainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Below is my code for the module "main_window" which implements the GUI of PyQT5.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(600, 300)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Form)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(500, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.pushButtonStart = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButtonStart.setObjectName("pushButtonStart")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButtonStart, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButtonStart.setText(_translate("Form", "Start"))
```

I wish to know why the GUI can not display all the standard output from the worker thread when the slot function "update_text" is inside the class for the worker thread. Must it be in the class for the main thread?

Comment: There are various issues with your code. First of all, the QRunnable subclasses are used in the wrong way: you should *not* use the `run` function, but start the QRunnable instance instead; then, and this is of utmost importance, no direct access to UI elements should **ever** happen from an external thread. Trying to do this almost always causes issues, from drawing problems to fatal crash. You **must** use signals and slots, and in this case it's usually better to directly use a QThread instead (since it natively supports signals, while QRunnable doesn't).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Originally, I coded in this way because I can't know how many worker threads there are going to be. I am making a program which allows users to monitor multiple consoles simultaneously and users can edit console ports which they want to use in the configuration file. I will change my code and bring about the application by the slot-and-signal mechanism as you suggest.